# Getting a row closest to the time for each row in another table

Tags: sql, sql-server

## The Problem:

Hi, I have a table with historical data from a bunch of sensors, and I am trying to get a row for each historical data record closest in time to the desired time. For instance I want to get the record closest to every minute.

*I have simplified the problem to the following, which if I can solve I can use to inform my general solution:*

Take two tables as follows:

```
CREATE TABLE [TempDataTable](
[DataIndex] [int] IDENTITY(0,2) NOT NULL,
[DataName] [varchar](40) NOT NULL,
[DataValue] [decimal](10,2) NOT NULL,
[DataTimeStamp] [datetime2](7)
)

CREATE TABLE [TempTargetTable](
[TargetIndex] [int] IDENTITY(1,2) NOT NULL,
[TargetTime] [datetime2](7)
)
```

For every row in `TempTargetTable`, get the row in `TempDataTable` with `TempDataTable.DataTimeStamp` closest to `TempTargetTable.TargetTime`

If I can do that, I am confident I can figure out the rest, but I am at a loss as to how to get this first step to work. For ease of testing your code, I can provide the following that populates both tables with some test data:

## Helpful test data:

```
INSERT INTO [TempDataTable]
    ([DataName],
    [DataValue],
    [DataTimeStamp])
VALUES
    ('Sensor',0,    '2017-01-01 00:00:00'),
    ('Sensor',0.5,  '2017-01-01 00:00:17'),
    ('Sensor',1,    '2017-01-01 00:01:03'),
    ('Sensor',1.5,  '2017-01-01 00:01:30'),
    ('Sensor',1.5,  '2017-01-01 00:01:38'),
    ('Sensor',2,    '2017-01-01 00:02:01'),
    ('Sensor',2.5,  '2017-01-01 00:02:15'),
    ('Sensor',3,    '2017-01-01 00:02:56'),
    ('Sensor',3.5,  '2017-01-01 00:03:27'),
    ('Sensor',4,    '2017-01-01 00:04:01'),
    ('Sensor',5,    '2017-01-01 00:05:00'),
    ('Sensor',5.5,  '2017-01-01 00:05:15'),
    ('Sensor',5.5,  '2017-01-01 00:05:46'),
    ('Sensor',6,    '2017-01-01 00:06:10'),
    ('Sensor',7,    '2017-01-01 00:06:57'),
    ('Sensor',7.5,  '2017-01-01 00:07:13'),
    ('Sensor',8,    '2017-01-01 00:08:01'),
    ('Sensor',9,    '2017-01-01 00:09:03')

INSERT INTO [TempTargetTable]
    ([TargetTime])
VALUES
    ('2017-01-01 00:00:00'),
    ('2017-01-01 00:01:00'),
    ('2017-01-01 00:02:00'),
    ('2017-01-01 00:03:00'),
    ('2017-01-01 00:04:00'),
    ('2017-01-01 00:05:00'),
    ('2017-01-01 00:06:00'),
    ('2017-01-01 00:07:00'),
    ('2017-01-01 00:08:00'),
    ('2017-01-01 00:09:00')
```

Comment: I would create a custom function for this, like getSensorByTime(time) In this function, calc the diffs between the times, order the diffs asc and limit 1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the current problem you are posting (the simplified one) I did the following:

Cross joined the tables to make the difference for each target time, with every existing data time stamp.
Then applied the `DENSE_RANK` function, which will provide a ranking for each TargetTime and then only selected those records with the minimum difference in milliseconds.

You can find a working solution [here](http://rextester.com/RURD86526).

```
 select TargetIndex, TargetTime, DataIndex, DataName, DataValue, DataTimeStamp
 from
  (
   select t.*, DENSE_RANK() OVER(PARTITION BY t.targetindex ORDER BY t.diff) as Rank
   from 
    (
      select tg.targetindex, tg.targettime, t.dataindex, t.dataname, t.datavalue, t.datatimestamp, abs(datediff(ms, tg.TargetTime, t.DataTimeStamp)) diff
      from TempDataTable t cross join TempTargetTable tg
    ) t
 ) f 
 where Rank = 1
```

Comment: Thank you so much, this worked perfectly! I had to make datediff the bigint version to prevent overflows, so for future people trying to follow this that may be necessary.

Answer (score 0):

If you want the first record in each calendar minute, you can use `row_number()`:

```
select tdt.*
from (select tdt.*,
             row_number() over (partition by format(DataTimeStamp, 'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm')
                                order by DataTimeStamp asc
                               ) as seqnum
      from TempDataTable tdt
     ) tdt
where seqnum = 1;
```

Comment: Gordon, missed a closing parenthesis after 'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm'.

Answer (score 0):

if I'm reading your question correct you want the closest record even when it is in the previous minute. If so you can you this query. I did it in multiple steps, so you can easily follow (I hope)

What I did:

- find the closest minute, if seconds >= 30 round up to the next minute else keep the actual minute
- calculate the difference in seconds and find the abs value of it
- get the closest value to the timepoint

Query

```
SELECT tempd.TargetTime, tdfinal.DataName, tdfinal.DataValue, tdfinal.DataTimeStamp
FROM @TempTargetTable as tempd
LEFT OUTER JOIN
   (SELECT tdseconds.*, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY closestMinute ORDER BY secondDiff) AS r
    FROM (SELECT td.*, ABS(DATEDIFF(SECOND, DataTimeStamp, closestMinute)) AS secondDiff
          FROM (SELECT DataName,DataValue,DataTimeStamp,
                  CONVERT(DATETIME,CONVERT(DATE, datatimestamp, 121)) + 
                  CONVERT (DATETIME,TIMEFROMPARTS(DATEPART(HOUR, datatimestamp), 
                             CASE WHEN DATEPART(SECOND, DataTimeStamp) >= 30 
                                    THEN DATEPART(MINUTE, DATATimeStamp) + 1 
                                    ELSE DATEPART(MINUTE, DATATimeStamp) END, 0,0,0), 121) AS closestMinute
                FROM @TempDataTable ) AS td
          ) AS tdseconds
   ) AS tdfinal
ON tdfinal.closestMinute = tempd.TargetTime
WHERE tdfinal.r = 1
```

Result

```
TargetTime               DataName  DataValue  DataTimeStamp
2017-01-01 00:00:00.000  Sensor    0.00       2017-01-01 00:00:00.000
2017-01-01 00:01:00.000  Sensor    1.00       2017-01-01 00:01:03.000
2017-01-01 00:02:00.000  Sensor    2.00       2017-01-01 00:02:01.000
2017-01-01 00:03:00.000  Sensor    3.00       2017-01-01 00:02:56.000
2017-01-01 00:04:00.000  Sensor    4.00       2017-01-01 00:04:01.000
2017-01-01 00:05:00.000  Sensor    5.00       2017-01-01 00:05:00.000
2017-01-01 00:06:00.000  Sensor    6.00       2017-01-01 00:06:10.000
2017-01-01 00:07:00.000  Sensor    7.00       2017-01-01 00:06:57.000
2017-01-01 00:08:00.000  Sensor    8.00       2017-01-01 00:08:01.000
2017-01-01 00:09:00.000  Sensor    9.00       2017-01-01 00:09:03.000
```